# Perspective of "億劫にならない" in this statement

Tags: grammar

> 顔面偏差値の差か、それとも日頃の行いのせいか、とにかく翔はいつも通り俺の隣でモテまくる。
>
> まあ今に始まった話じゃないけど、翔のヤツこれでよく色々と億劫にならないな。

Context: 翔 is being popular with the ladies at the moment.

> Maybe its cuz of his good looks, or how he conducts himself on a daily basis, anyways, kakeru like always, is beside me with the girls fawning over him.
>
> ... or maybe what I just said isn't the case, kakeru, this bastard, must (want/) to be so variously annoying. (kakeru is the host of a meetup, and probably doesn't want to get the way of the development of possible relationships).

Is the speaker not wanting 翔 to これでよく色々と億劫 or is the speaker saying that 翔 doesn't want to これでよく色々と億劫?

The latter makes more logical sense but the sentence still feels very strange.

Comment: 「まあ今に始まった話ではないけど」は "maybe what I just said isn't the case" て意味じゃないです。。 "That's nothing new" とか "This is not the first time" みたいな意味です

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「（よく/よくも）　～～～～（ね/な）」 is a commonly used phrasing that indicates amazement at how someone is able to accomplish something, although not always on a positive note.

> あんなに汚かった部屋をよくこんなに綺麗に掃除できたね。
>
> It's amazing how you were able to clean up such a messy room.
>
> 目の前で９０歳のおばあさんが立っているのによくもすわっていられるな。
>
> It's amazing how you can stay seated when there's a 90 year old grandma standing right in front of you.

So in this case,

> よく色々と億劫にならないな。

would mean something close to

> It's amazing how he doesn't get annoyed at all that

Comment: 「...よく**も**こんなに綺麗に掃除できた...」はおかしいです。「よくも～～」は "How dare you~~!" っていう negative な感じになるので、「よくも...掃除できた/した(ね)」とか言うと掃除したことに対して怒っている感じになります。「...よくこんなにきれいに掃除できたね」にした方がいいと思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。修正致しました。