# Meaning of よく住める

Tags: meaning

I came across this sentence in an exercise, so there is no context :

> こんなに寒い部屋に**よく住めるね**。

What is exactly the meaning of よく住める and is it possible to have one or two other sentences using it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here よく means *how (can/do you) ...?*, indicating the speaker thinks '...' is something extraordinary. It is somewhat close to *how come ...?*.

So the sentence means *how can you live in such a cold room like this? (I think it's impossible)*.

Incidentally よく can be put at the front: よくこんな寒い部屋に住めるね.

---

Other examples:

- よくこんなもの見つけたね *How did you find such a thing? (I am surprised you did)*
- よくそんなこと言えるね *How dare you say such a thing?*
- よく日本語なんか勉強するね *How come you study Japanese!*

Note that it often comes with そんな/こんな or なんか (roughly corresponding to *such*).

---

デジタル大辞泉 lists this usage of よく(well) as [separate definitions](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%88%E3%81%8F/#jn-227079_):

> ４ 困難なことをしたり、考えられないような喜ばしい結果を得たりして感じ入るさま。本当にまあ。よくぞ。「―来てくれました」「月給だけで―やっていけるね」
>
> ５ 相手の非常識な言動などを非難するさま。4を反語的にいう語。よくもまあ。「―のこのこと来られたものだ」

5 is the definition for *how dare..*.

That said, I suppose it can be understood as an exclamation. E.g. the sentence in question is *how well you live in such a cold room!* and the speaker thinks you are doing too well (much).

---

In terms of register, it is colloquial, but can be made polite. E.g. よくこんな寒い部屋に住めますね.

Ending with な (e.g. 住めるな) would sound masculine and somewhat more rude.

Comment: I've never come across this usage of よく before. It would be great of you could give a few more details. Is this from よい (good), よく (often), or something entirely different? Is it standard Japanese, or does it have a more modern/slang feel? How does ね fit in? Is it part of the structure? I don't see how it would work in the usual sense of asking for confirmation. Thanks.

Comment: @user3856370 I think this was originally a sarcasm, but it's no longer slangy. (But it's of course not very polite, either.) See [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5651/5010) and [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61316/5010). You can use other sentence-final particles like な, or just say "よくも! (How dare you!)", "よくまあ (Ooh I'm amazed!)", etc.

Comment: @user3856370 I added the answers to your questions.

Comment: よく女子供が殺せるな was used to translate the line "How can you shoot women and children?" in the famous ["get some" scene of _Fullmetal Jacket_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5voVVhel4YY) together with its double meaning.