# Meaning of a sentence with ああも+potential

Tags: grammar, translation

I came across this line in a game recently:

> Aが焼き芋を勧めてきたけれど、焼いただけの芋をああもよく喜んで食べられるね

I've been struggling to decipher the second part of the sentence. From another line showing the other character's perspective:

> Bに焼き芋を勧めたら、断られてしもたわ。焦げてたからあかんかったんかなぁ……

I know that it was possibly the sweet potato being burnt that was the problem, and based on that my best guess is that the first line means something like:

> "A offered me a baked potato, but, well, a potato that has been *baked only* you could enjoy yourself eating somehow [except that one was *burnt*, and so I couldn't eat it]".

What makes me unsure about it is that I can't really find anything in the original sentence that would point out how the potato being edible was not the case (note how much of my translation goes in the brackets, and the "well" I added in) — I don't see any contrastive elements besides that けど, which feels to me rather "weak" and not clear in what it's referring to, and I believe that if it weren't for the second line I wouldn't be able to figure out the first one at all. 
The ああも is also a little confusing to me, since I haven't really encountered it (as in ああ+も) much before. Googling around, I found [some](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%82%E3%82%82) [sentences](https://emuzu-2.cocolog-nifty.com/blog/2020/10/post-9eb07f.html) phrased like こうもああも+potential form, mirroring the one at hand save for the こうも. However I failed to find any explanation of this structure, which makes me assume it should just be understood literally ("you can do X like this and you can do it like that"). I'd like to know whether my understanding is correct and whether that kind of phrasing has any relation to the one used in the sentence in question.
Is my interpretation of the sentence correct? If so, what am I missing that would make its meaning clear? And if not, what does it actually mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, 焦げてた does mean *burnt* but I guess here it just means *burnt but edible*. Also, you may be aware by the picture but 焼き芋 is typically baked *sweet* potato not what is called *baked potato* in English.

The pattern is よく＋potential rather than ああも+potential. See the question below.

- [Meaning of よく住める](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93955/45489)

ああも is [ああ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%82%E3%81%82/#je-1)+も and means あのように=*like that*. Here it modifies 喜んで or 喜んで食べられる. Thus the sentence means

> How can one(you) eat sweet potatoes that are just baked with pleasure like that?

implying the speaker does not like baked sweet potatoes in general.

---

The following means the same and may be easier to parse

> よく焼いただけの芋をああも喜んで食べられるね